# Run Powershell C# On A Non English Machine

Tags: c#, powershell

I am generating a powershell script via C# code. I then save the script and make a call to the command prompt via C# to run the created script. This works fine on an English machine, but when I try to run the code on a German machine it can't read the English script code.

I tried to add a culture detection to the code, but it still doesn't seem to fly

```
            //Create MyScript
            sb.AppendLine("function MyCustomFunction ([string]$input) {");
            //...powershell function created I am using

            //Make a function to detect current machine language
            sb.AppendLine("function Using-Culture (");
            sb.AppendLine("[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]$culture,");
            sb.AppendLine("[ScriptBlock]$script)");
            sb.AppendLine("{");
            sb.AppendLine("    $OldCulture = [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture");
            sb.AppendLine("    trap");
            sb.AppendLine("    {");
            sb.AppendLine("    [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = $OldCulture");
            sb.AppendLine("    }");
            sb.AppendLine("    [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = $culture");
            sb.AppendLine("    $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.InvokeScript($script)");
            sb.AppendLine("    [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = $OldCulture");
            sb.AppendLine("}");

            //Call my function after detecting the language
            sb.AppendLine("Using-Culture " + langCode + " {");    
            sb.AppendLine("MyCustomFunction  " + someInput);                
            sb.AppendLine("}");


            //....save the stringbuilder to a file

            //Run powershell via command prompt
            command.Run(@"powershell.exe",
                    @"-ExecutionPolicy Bypass " + @"& '" + The_Script_I_Created +"'",
                    out output,
                    out errors);
```

Comment: Totally not going to help you, but I'm curious why you aren't just doing this in C# entirely?

Comment: @EBGreen things I wanna do cannot be handled by C# but can be handled by powershell.

Comment: I find that hard to believe. Powershell is running .Net code.

Comment: Ok. Let's just say if I wanted to do it this way how can it be done?

Comment: What happens when you run it on a German machine, say?

Comment: Well, in the script that you are creating you are literally using .Net classes so I would guess you would do the same thing with those same classes but in C#.

Comment: If it's the original `MyCustomFunction` which causes issues, and adding language detection didn't help anything, why wouldn't you show us the function?

Comment: @JanneTuukkanen We can assume MYCustomFunction works as expected on English machines

Comment: I've had issues with cmdlets in PowerShell and Bat script on non-english machines in the past. The solve was to be very specific with the command. `robocopy` failed but `"C:\Windows\System32\Robocopy.exe"` worked.